# You can't specify target table 'rinexo' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

The output of this query gives me the duplicate rows in a table,

```
select * from rinex1 where rid not in 
  (select min(rid) from rinex1 group by rinex_version,type);
```

now i want to delete them using the this query,

```
delete from rinex1 where rid not in 
  (select min(rid) from rinex1 group by rinex_version,type);
```

It gives the following error saying :

> You can't specify target table 'rinexo' for update in FROM clause

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
DELETE FROM rinex1 
WHERE rid NOT IN 
    (SELECT MIN(rid) 
     FROM rinex1 
     GROUP BY rinex_version, type
    ) AS p ;
```

Comment: HEY thanks for the answer, but it  gives me this error :ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS p' at line 1